# lm317t charger with a load?

Tags: lm317

I have a plan to make a solar charger for battery and at the same time power a load.I want to use lm317t to keep constant current.I can not find any reference on how a lm317t effects a solar panel charger with a load.the battery I am charging is 2000mah 7.2 volt battery with a 9volt solar panel.I want the panel to charge the battery and send excess current to load.What would schemetic be how would lm317t fit in this situation.

Comment: So, you want to apply a constant current to the battery, while allowing any additional current produced by the solar panel to power a load? So I guess the load is not connected to the battery then? Or does this circuit also have to allow the load to be powered from the battery?

Comment: it also has to allow the load to be powered from the battery too

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want to do very easily. You want to trickle charge the battery, and have excess solar panel current go to the load, but then if the solar panel output is not sufficient, you want the battery to power the load. This is much more complex than can be achieved with the LM317.

Comment: What do you recommend different battery or ic

Comment: It is complicated. I have to ask a lot of questions. Do you know what your load is like? Is it somewhat constant current, or is it highly variable? And is it powered on all the time, or sometimes on and sometimes off? If it is constant current, what is the current?

Comment: The load is robot so it has motors which cause the current to vary and when nothing is moving it draws current for arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your other post. So the solar cells provide around 200 mA. The battery capacity is 2000 mAh. My advice is to just connect the solar panels directly to the battery and load. Connect it all together. But don't leave it like that indefinitely or the life of the batteries will be shortened. If you are not using the robot for a few days, disconnect the panels from the battery to avoid over-charge. In order to do something better, you would need to charge the batteries at a much higher rate and use dV/dt or dT/dt charge termination. For example, if you could charge at 1A, then you could probably use a dedicated charger IC with built-in timer and dT/dt charge termination. It is possible that you will end up destroying the batteries this way, but if you discharge them substantially every day, most likely it will be OK.

Comment: the voltage will be 9v and 200mah and i can connect it directly right

Comment: In this case, think of the solar cells as a current source. They will supply 200 mA to the batteries, and the batteries decide what the voltage will be. This is an approximation, but the solar cells will provide 200 mA with only slight variation over a wide Voltage range. Meanwhile, the batteries will maintain voltage (it will slowly rise during charge and decrease during discharge) over a wide range of currents. So the panels choose the current, and the batteries choose the voltage. So the voltage will depend on state of charge, and cell temperature and perhaps other things as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad idea.

Since you are talking about a 7.2 volt battery, it is a NIMH unit, and these do not do well under trickle charge conditions. See, for instance, http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_nickel_metal_hydride

Comment: It won't be overcharged because the solar panel can only provide a good charge for 6 hours before it get cloudy or dark and it will be limited.I really just want to know how to hook it up

Comment: If the battery won't be overcharged, the it will almost certainly be discharged.